# Expressing $\mathbb{R} P^3$ as a fibre bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, projective-space, fiber-bundles

This question came up in office hours with my differential topology prof and since then I've almost settled on an answer.

The question was whether we could write $\mathbb{R} P^3$ as a fiber bundle with base space $\mathbb{R} P^2$. We spent a few moments thinking about it before deciding it wasn't relevant to the conversation at hand and moved on. Since then I've done some reading and become aware of a result that says if $M, N$ are compact and connected smooth manifolds and $f:M\rightarrow N$ is a submersion, then the fibers of $f$ are all diffeomorphic to a manifold $F$, and this gives rise to a fibre bundle with total space $M$, fiber $F$ and base $N$. Following that, I wrote a function

$$f: \mathbb{R}P^3 \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}P^2$$

defined on homogeneous coordinates by

$$(x,y,z,w) \mapsto (x,y,z).$$

$f$ is well-defined, smooth, and unless I've made a silly mistake in calculating Jacobians it's also a submersion. Now, I'm having trouble understanding what the preimage $f^{-1}(p)$ for $p \in \mathbb{R}P^2$ is. Is it simply $\mathbb{R}$ or is it something more complicated than that?

Comment: $f$ does not define a map. For example, where does (0,0,0,1) get sent to?

Comment: Could you use the fact that $\mathbb{R}P^3$ is diffeomorphic to $SO(3)$?

Comment: @David: Hold on, I was reading the wrong page of my notes when I transcribed this. I had an actual map somewhere.

Comment: Well I found it but it's sort of a moot point now that user86418 provided a very clean solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $f:S^3 \to S^2$ be the Hopf map, and $\pi:S^3 \to \mathbf{RP}^{2}$ the composition with the projection $S^2 \to \mathbf{RP}^{2}$. The map $\pi$ sends antipodes of $S^{3}$ to the same place (since the Hopf map collepses equatorial circles), so $\pi$ factors through the projection $S^{3} \to \mathbf{RP}^{3}$. It's "clear" this expresses $\mathbf{RP}^{3}$ as a bundle over $\mathbf{RP}^{2}$ whose fibres are pairs of circles.

**Added in edit**: I couldn't get @Sanath Devalapurkar's idea (using $SO(3)$) to work, probably because the fibres aren't subgroups, but it did suggest an alternative, and arguably more geometric/elementary construction. View $\mathbf{RP}^{3} \simeq SO(3)$ as the total space $US^{2}$ of the unit circle bundle over $S^2$. (The first column $A_{1}$ of a matrix $A$ in $SO(3)$ is a unit vector, a.k.a., point of $S^2$, and the second column $A_{2}$ is an orthogonal unit vector, a.k.a., a unit tangent vector at $A_{1}$;  since $\det A = 1$, these columns uniquely determine $A_{3} = A_{1} \times A_{2}$.) The fibration $US^{2} \to \mathbf{RP}^{2}$ in question is the projection $US^{2} \to S^2$ followed by the quotient $S^2 \to \mathbf{RP}^{2}$; the fibre over a point $[p]$ in $\mathbf{RP}^{2}$ is the pair of unit circles over the antipodal points $\{p, -p\}$ of $S^2$.

Comment: Small oops: The fibre isn't a circle, but a _pair_ of circles, each sitting over one of a pair of antipodal points in $S^2$. (The fibres of $f$ in $S^{3}$ are pairs of circles in orthogonal planes in $\mathbf{R}^{4}$, and each circle gets quotiented by its antipodal map.)

Comment: Wait, I was following you up until your parenthetical remark. I thought the fibres of the Hopf fibration were simply circles, as opposed to pairs of circles?

Comment: Recursive oops; where I wrote "...fibres of $f$", please read "...fibres of $\pi$". :)